# Add multiple columns in custom WordPress table if it does not exist

Tags: wordpress

I make a plug-in in word press and create some tables, during upgrading the plug-in i need to add columns to existing table, i want to add columns to table if they are not exist in the table.How can i do so ?

Comment: Are we talking about a database or HTML tables? Please update tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use this query (change the table name and column name)

```
$row = $wpdb->get_results(  "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'wp_customer_say' AND column_name = 'say_state'"  );

if(empty($row)){
   $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE wp_customer_say ADD say_state INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1");
}
```